# Qt models with intertwined updates

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to Qt and trying to figure out how I should build my models. Here's the situation (I have complete ownership over everything).

I have a data class which is something like this:

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data();

    void addValue(int newValue);
    void removeValue(int indexToRemove);
    // Other access functions

private:
    void recalculate();

    QList<int> values;
    int aggregatedValue;
};
```

The public functions add or remove values from the `QList` and call the private function, which recalculates the aggregated value (otherwise unaccessible), which is a statistical index of the list - think of it as a mean of list's value.

Now I have to build models to show this data.

**Question 1**: is it a good idea to build a big tree model with one branch containing the list and the other containing the aggregated value? I tried a bit, but wasn't able to easily build it so that *it would have fixed depth and fixed number of children in a certain branch*. Within such a big model, the `setData` function will emit signals to notify views that not only the list, but also the aggregated value has changed.

Being unable to make a tree model work, I've built two distinct model, `listModel` and `aggregatedModel`, with the latter being a read-only model. The problem is, how do I force the update of widget using `aggregatedModel` when a new value is inserted into the list?

I've come up with 2 solutions: create a super model which is responsible for connecting `listModel` and `aggregatedModel`, that is a class that intercepts the `dataChanged()` signals from the `listModel`, calls `recalculate()` and then emits the `dataChanged()` signals from `aggregatedModel` in order to force views to update; or make the `Data` class a `QObject` to be able to send a signal when the aggregated value changes (inside `recalculate()`) and connect `aggregatedModel` to it.

**Question 2**: what is the most common solution? I like the idea of having actual data class as pure c++ class - that is, not a `QObject`, so no overhead, much more portable through projects - but the latter solution seems more flexible and easy to organize, with the added benefit that if I use different models to display/edit the same information, I can do it easily.

**Question 3**: let's suppose I have a second data class, `PooledData`, which pools certain values from many `Data` objects. It contains pointers to the pooled data (actual data are not simple integer but more complex structures). On top of this I have to build a model which reacts to changes in the data pointed to. How can I do this?

Comment: For question 1, do you intend to show each value from the `QList` as a tree item? In other words, if you clicked on the node that represents the `Data` object, would it expand to show a bunch of children that represent its `values` member?

Comment: I need it to be structured like this: (empty) root node with two children; (empty) children 1 with items from the list as children; (empty) children two with the aggregated value - values, most probably - as children. So, just to be clear, the whole model will factor in only one data member (more or less, 2 separated list put together).
I'm not actually going to show these in a tree view, though. The tree model is just for enabling the whole "update the aggregated value" logic to be put in one place, while I will show subset of the tree in list/table view as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with one model. I would subclass `QAbstractItemModel`, and in the `setData` function where you would respond to changes to the list, emit a `dataChanged` signal for both the changed list item and the index that represents the aggregated value. I would definitely NOT make my Data class emit the signals itself if it's managed by a model. Handling user input and signalling changes in the underlying data is strictly the job of the model.

For your second question, I personally like to use non-Qt classes to hold the actual data, then use the Qt models as interfaces between my classes and proxy models, views, etc. I'm pretty sure this is how the whole model-view system is intended to be used.

For your third question, just connect the `dataChanged` signal from your Data model to a slot in the pooled data model. That slot should do all the appropriate calculations, then emit another signal that it has changed. If you set up all your signals from the first model properly, it becomes fairly easy to react to them properly in the second model.